# BackgroundColorSpan hides text selection color android

Tags: java, android

I used BackgroundColorSpan to highlight some text TextView using the follow lines of code

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
 text.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW),start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
 textView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

but when I select those text the BackgroundColorSpan hides the text selection color as seen in the screen shot. I want text selection color appear over BackgroundColorSpan. Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because **SpannableString** is rendered by **TextView** and text selection is controlled by contextual **ActionMode**, I don't think there is a straightforward way to make them work together. However there is a workaround.

The first part of the solution is to implement **CustomSelectionModeCallback** to get which part of the text is currently selected.

```
textView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        //
        // This function is called whenever the selected text is 
        // changed, so you can use this to keep track of which part
        // the text is currently selected
        //
        int start = textView.getSelectionStart();
        int end = textView.getSelectionEnd();
        String slectedText =textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end));
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }
});
```

The second part of the solution is to calculate the intersection between the selected text and the text is currently highlighted by **SpannableString**, and not to highlight the intersected portion. As you may need to change this at runtime, you might want to use **[SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but what I exactly want is that the text selection color, which has opacity, will overlay on BackgroundColorSpan so that both the colors are visible.

Comment: In that case, you can use **Color.argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)** to replace **Color.YELLOW** in **new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW)**. The first **alpha** term will give you transparency (0-255).